# Get input from serial port on tspl?

Tags: printing, serial-port, tspl

I have a tsc printer (TC210) and a scale with serial port, I'm trying to get the weight info to be printed using TSPL, I have 2 problems:
- I have to enter other values with a keyboard (I'm using INPUT command for this) and this command works both for USB and Serial, and the scale is messing things up here, as I want to only get input from the USB Keyboard.
- I don't know how to get actual values from the scale, I tried with INP and INP$ but it's not receiving anything.

Comment: Code? Please? What is `INP`? What programming language are you talking about?

Comment: TSPL is the language, here: http://www.tscprinters.com/cms/upload/download_en/TSPL_TSPL2_Programming.pdf

Answer (score 0):

According to the SET USBHOST command in the programming manual, it seems that only the keyboard or scanner can be connected to the USB host connector.
If you want to connect the scale, it seems to be only the serial port.

Please check and experiment with the following items.
- When using the scale with the serial port, check with the diagnostic tool or the SET COM1 command to see if it matches the baud rate etc. of the scale.
- Try several ways of connecting pins, such as straight or cross.
- Connect PC instead of scale and experiment to see if it can read/write with PC terminal software.